# I Got error on add angular material in my project... I use angular 15 and node version 18.14 and npm version 9.6.0

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got this error when I add angular material

I use this command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

this error shows

> ℹ Using package manager: npm
> ✖ Unable to load package information from registry: request to https://registry.npmmirror.com/@angular%2fmaterial failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:2280:12e:0:3::3fc:443

I also use this command

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angulterial @angular/cdk
```

this also error shows

> fy:safevalues: timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-addon-api Comp[############......] / reify:safevalues: timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-addon-api Comp[############......] / reify:safevalues: timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-addon-api Comp[############......] / reify:safevalues: timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-addon-api Comp[############......] / reify:safevaluenpm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
> npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
> npm ERR! network request to https://cdn.npmmirror.com/packages/%40material/progress-indicator/15.0.0-canary.b994146f6.0/progress-indicator-15.0.0-canary.b994146f6.0.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\rocky\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-16T11_41_10_681Z-debug-0.log

How I successfully add angular material please guide me